# How to use unnest array with dynamic Postgresql query across two tables

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, unnest

I am relatively new to SQL and having some difficulty understanding how to run a conditional query. For some context, this query is being run with Node/Express using Postgresql.

**Situation**

If a user selects 'Team A' the query (in the backend) will take the data from one table, while if the user selects 'Team B' it will run the query against a different table. To render the table correctly I need to transpose the data and understand I can achieve this with `UNNEST(array[])`.

I can run the query successfully with the following code:

```
SELECT "TeamA" AS "Player",
          UNNEST(array['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2']) AS "Type",
          UNNEST(array["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"]) AS "Type2",
          UNNEST(array["Column4", "Column5", "Column6"]) AS "Type3",
          UNNEST(array["Column7", "Column8", "Column9"]) AS "Type4",
          UNNEST(array["Column10", "Column11", "Column12"]) AS "Type5"
      FROM sportingdb."TeamAData"
      WHERE "TeamA" = '${player}'
```

However this needs to be dynamic and query a different table if the user selects 'Team A' or 'Team B'.

I have attempted to use the same query with a ternary, however was given a syntax error and am unable to identify where I have gone wrong. I also broke it down as an `if else` statement as follows:

```
DO
BEGIN
    IF '${TeamA}' = "TeamA" THEN
    SELECT "TeamA" AS "Player",
          UNNEST(array['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2']) AS "Type",
          UNNEST(array["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"]) AS "Type2",
          UNNEST(array["Column4", "Column5", "Column6"]) AS "Type3",
          UNNEST(array["Column7", "Column8", "Column9"]) AS "Type4",
          UNNEST(array["Column10", "Column11", "Column12"]) AS "Type5"
      FROM sportingdb."TeamAData"
      WHERE "TeamA" = '${player}'
    ELSE
    SELECT "TeamB" AS "Player",
          UNNEST(array['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2']) AS "Type",
          UNNEST(array["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"]) AS "Type2",
          UNNEST(array["Column4", "Column5", "Column6"]) AS "Type3",
          UNNEST(array["Column7", "Column8", "Column9"]) AS "Type4",
          UNNEST(array["Column10", "Column11", "Column12"]) AS "Type5"
      FROM sportingdb."TeamBData"
      WHERE "TeamB" = '${player}'
 END IF
 END
```

I found this [link](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/postgresql-if-else-statement-with-examples/) was somewhat helpful, which I followed to write the above code but arrived with an SQL error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN". I also tried adding the dollar signs as per the example as well as a `DECLARE` line but this didn't seem to work.

I would truly appreciate any assistance on how I can get this to work. Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Do you really have one table for each team? That sounds like a bad design decision. You should have a single `team` table that contains a column that identifies the team.

Comment: No, I have changed over the names for privacy reasons just in case